# Android Studio closing automatically after updating MACBook Pro - ERROR_CGDataProviderCreateWithData_BufferIsNotReadable+0x10

Tags: android

Android Studio Getting closed if I edit anything in code.

I have tried with Android Studio stable version and Preview Canary Version also, still getting same issue.

How to fix this ??

Getting following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff33e05930, pid=1343, tid=0x0000000000011f43
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b01) (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.152-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [CoreGraphics+0x195930]  ERROR_CGDataProviderCreateWithData_BufferIsNotReadable+0x10
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fe2ef9db800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0 3.4#AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156 Studio, eap:false, os:Mac OS X 10.15, java-version:JetBrains s.r.o 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01" [_thread_in_native, id=73539, stack(0x000070000d77d000,0x000070000d87d000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the enhancements IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 that come with the build, Mac OS X users will find a new experimental feature called “Switch IDE Boot JDK”, available from the Find Action popup:

[image]

This feature lets you choose a JDK under which to run IntelliJ IDEA, which should help those Mac users who don’t have Java 6 installed on their machines.